# destructive map operator for python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, operators

In ruby, the array function has at least two methods for map. The first `map`, creates a copy of the array, with the function operated on. The original array is unchanged. The second, `map!`, changes the array itself, and does not create a copy. This can be beneficial if one has a huge array. Is that possible in Python 3.4?
Thanks.

Comment: Sure, write a for loop and modify in-place.

Comment: Python list does shallow copy. For deepcopy you can use `lst[:]`.

Comment: It is not a copy per-se, the idea is not to have 2 arrays in the memory.

Comment: The answer to the question is no. There's no built-in function that does this, you have to write an explicit loop.

Comment: It would be very simple for you to define your own function that does it, though.

Comment: No arguments. But it is usually better to use something built in than one's own brew.

Comment: You realize that if memory efficiency is your concern, that map returns a lazy iterator? You can just do `my_list[:] = map(f, my_list)` if you want to modify in-place, or better yet, continue using lazy operations on your `map` object

Comment: I didn't know that it was a lazy operator. This does explain my performance benchmarks.